# Laravel get values for Authenticated User only

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

Does laravel provide a more efficient way to only get values for the authenticated user instead of repeating the following line for every model type.

```
$cards = Auth::user()->cards; 
$books = Auth::user()->books;
$friends = Auth::user()->friends;
.........
```

I can see how this can be accomplished by a middleware but wanted to see if laravel provides anything out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load relationships using eloquent's "with" method.

Comment: That helps a little but I will have to repeat that in multiple classes as well.

Comment: Combine this with query scopes and it should cut down quite a bit on code duplication